# Android Internal Error while Checked Preview for all Screen Sizes option

Tags: android, eclipse

I have found a new error to my layout xml file screen. Many times i have done before that but today i have faced strange issue.  While I have checked "***Preview for all Screen Sizes***" option for my xml file then it loaded but not display image on that particular screen.

When i clicked on that particular screen then it is opened in main xml file but in preview for screen size doesn't display and give me internal error. So please anybody suggest for this.

My Image is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But than I changed API from 19 to 10 and the problem gone! As I see on the picture you are using API 19. Try to change it to 10 or even 18!

Answer (score 0):

yes, I tried to change the API to 18 it works.
I think there is a problem in displaying the "preview all screens" in API 19 ... at least for now.

Comment: how to change api 19 to 18.

Comment: open your layout.xml with graphical layout, there is a button with android logo with api number(as show in pic up), you can change it. if you have no choices you have to install other apis from android SDK Manager.